# UDP Commmunication Data Lost

Tags: windows, udp, packet

I have one unit that continuously sends 18 different camera images to different ports via UDP. It sends each image line by line, marking the line number. When I watch with Wireshark on a computer, the amount of instant data incoming is approximately 500Mbps, but when I switch to the other computer, it drops to approximately 250Mbps. When I run the software from which I took the image, I observe that some lines do not appear in the image.

It works fine on my old Windows 7 computer. When I switched to another Windows 7 computer, I observed that it was not working properly again, and it was fixed when I uploaded the image backup file from the other one to this computer. Now I need to run it properly on a Windows 10 computer. How can I do it? I think the problem is caused by Windows. Do you have any information about which parameter I should correct?